# Is there a size limit for Pandas read_table()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a `.dat` file, `filename.dat`, and I wish to read this into a Pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('filename.dat')
```

Is there a size limit regarding this? I was hoping to save the columns of a dataframe individually for a file of size 1 TB. Is this possible?

Comment: it's possible, if the resulting DF can fit into the memory. Use `chunksize` parameter in order to read big file in chunks - this will consume much less memory

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it if you don't have memory, like @MaxU says. If you were doing rows it would be better to use [buffering](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) with `chunksize` mentioned by @MaxU or setting `iterator` to True. But for columns and a large file this seems risky.

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom Any other recommendations?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang I've never dealt with a file that big. I've only stored up to a gigabyte in memory and then a BufferOverflowError occured. Everything depends on your system. I recommend trying [root's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38445308/5645103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the usage of `chunksize` mentioned in the comments, I'd do something like the following:

```
chunks = pd.read_table('filename.dat', chunksize=10**5)
fileout = 'filname_{}.dat'
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    mode = 'w' if i == 0 else 'a'
    header = i == 0
    for col in chunk.columns:
        chunk[col].to_csv(fileout.format(col), index=False, header=header, mode=mode)
```

You'll probably want to experiment with the `chunksize` parameter to see what's most efficient for your data.

The reason I'm using `enumerate` is to create a new file with a header when the first chunk is read in, and append without a header for subsequent chunks.